# Retrofit android: gson array content deserialization

Tags: android, json, deserialization, retrofit

I'm working on API Requests with Retrofit(1.9.0) and gson library (1.7.0 I have compatibility issues with version 2.3.1 of gson) on Android, I make some request to an API which have same format of response but different content following the url call, but I encounter a problem for a deserialization of one answer which there is array inside. This is an example of the json I want to deserialize :

```
{
   "http_code":200,
   "content":[
      {
         "name":"Groult Christian",
         "location":[
            48.897655,
            2.252462
         ],
         "website":null,
         "address":{
            "street_address":"XXXXXX",
            "city":"XXXXXX",
            "state":null,
            "postal_code":"XXXXXX",
            "country":"XXXXXX"
         },
         "global_score":0,
         "popularity_score":0,
         "quality_score":0,
         "createdAt":"2015-02-18T02:13:05.068Z",
         "updatedAt":"2015-02-18T02:13:05.068Z",
         "id":"54e3f531775288ca572872ac"
      },
      ...
   ]
}
```

My DeserializerJson and how I call it for retrofit:

```
    public class DeserializerJson<T> implements JsonDeserializer<T> {

        @Override
        public T deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc)
                throws JsonParseException
        {
            // Get the "content" element from the parsed JSON
            JsonElement content = je.getAsJsonObject().get("content");

            // Deserialize it. You use a new instance of Gson to avoid infinite recursion
            // to this deserializer
            return new Gson().fromJson(content, type);

        }
    }
...
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(ContentUser.class, new DeserializerJson<ContentUser>())
                .registerTypeAdapter(DeviceInfo.class, new DeserializerJson<DeviceInfo>())
                .registerTypeAdapter(PlacesModel.class, new DeserializerJson<PlacesModel>())
                .create();

        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.BASIC)
                .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
                ...
...
```

and my different models:

```
public class PlacesModel {
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("location")
    @Expose
    private List<Double> location = new ArrayList<Double>();
    @SerializedName("website")
    @Expose
    private Object website;
    @SerializedName("address")
    @Expose
    private AddressModel address;
    @SerializedName("global_score")
    @Expose
    private Integer globalScore;
    @SerializedName("popularity_score")
    @Expose
    private Integer popularityScore;
    @SerializedName("quality_score")
    @Expose
    private Integer qualityScore;
    @SerializedName("createdAt")
    @Expose
    private String createdAt;
    @SerializedName("updatedAt")
    @Expose
    private String updatedAt;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;

   /* Getters and Setters... */
}

public class AddressModel {

    @SerializedName("street_address")
    @Expose
    private String streetAddress;
    @SerializedName("city")
    @Expose
    private String city;
    @SerializedName("state")
    @Expose
    private Object state;
    @SerializedName("postal_code")
    private String postalCode;
    @SerializedName("country")
    @Expose
    private String country;

    /* Getters and Setters... */
}
```

url call in Api Manager is like this:

```
@GET("/places")
public void getPlaces(RestCallback<List<PlacesModel>> callback);
```

But when I do the call I get this error : `com.google.gson.JsonParseException: The JsonDeserializer com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter@3b8aa06 failed to deserialize json object`

Everything is fine for other call I get all content and so with no problem but one where there is array inside content I got an error and I don't understand why I believed if I just put a list of my model it will be fine but it doesn't work.
I think I miss something  so if someone can help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that the full stack trace? If it isn't, please post the full stack trace in your question.

Comment: Yeah it's almost the full stack trace, after this error there is just the json I want to deserialize

Comment: Is there a line number in the stack trace that shows the part of your code causing the `JsonParseException`?

Comment: Nope, but  this is message is display inside failure function in this : 
`apiManager.getPlaces(new RestCallback<List<PlacesModel>>() 
{
            @Override
            public void failure(RestError restError) 
           {
                Log.d("TEST", restError.getStrMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void success(List<PlacesModel> placesModels, Response response) {
                Log.d("TEST", "test");
            }
        });`

Comment: @flo3573358 I resolve your issue, Please inform me if that works

Comment: It works, Thank you very much, I have an idea it was about this stuff but I didn't think to put class list on the method. Thank you again

Comment: @flo3573358 I am glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your issue is that you register `DeserializerJson` for `PlacesModel` class and in getPlaces method your response is `List<PlacesModel>` class. `List<PlacesModel>` is a different class as `PlacesModel`so Gson doesn't know how to deserialise `List<PlacesModel>`. What you have to do is register one more Deserialiser by this method:

```
.registerTypeAdapter(List.class, new DeserializerJson<List<PlacesModel>>())
```

If you use more than one type of `List` (I mean `List<PlacesModel>` and `List< DeviceInfo >`) You can define your own `TypeAdapter` or you cN change list to array and register deserialiser for them as is shown below

```
.registerTypeAdapter(PlacesModel[].class, new DeserializerJson<PlacesModel[]>())
```

Now everything works fine for yours json.